# Verifying availability in a scheduling table MySql PHP

Tags: mysql

I currently have a table that holds events with the following columns :

```
ID  | Date_From |   Date_To |   Time_From  |    Time_To
```

When a user wants to create a new event through a form, I am trying to write the query that will verify if an event is already existent during the requested time-slot and return a number of rows for further processing.

I'm not certain about how to proceed for the query to verify the existence of an event during that time frame.

The end user is providing the same 4 fields as above.

Both date fields in the yyyy-mm-dd format and times as 00:00:00;

Thank you in advance for any tips you could provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of managing date and time separately use datetime filed. Please check my table structure (table name is meeting).

[image]

And the table with some sample data.

[image]

After that, you can run MySQL query to check the given time is there on the table or not. For your reference, I have given you a sample query. Hope this will help you.

SELECT * FROM `meeting` WHERE ('2018-03-08 10:00:00' between `start_date_time` and `end_date_time`) AND ('2018-03-08 13:00:00' between `start_date_time` and `end_date_time`);

Comment: Yet it's returning an `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` error... I'm not certain why

Comment: So I used exactly the same formatting as you suggested, the one I copied below and it's returning the above response...

Comment: Ok. Are you facing any issue?

Comment: It's returning the `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` error. 

Am I correct that to use the value of a variable as the table name, I can use : `SELECT * FROM` `$variable` `?

Comment: with there being ` around the $variable ?

Comment: `$Instructavailverifysql = "SELECT * FROM ^$instructor_table^ WHERE ('$FromDateTime' between start_date_time and end_date_time) AND ('$ToDateTime' between start_date_time and end_date_time) LIMIT 1";
 $instructtavailquery = mysqli_query($db_conx4, $Instructavailverifysql);
 $instructavailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($instructtavailquery);`

replacing ` with ^ above for display in this comnt. 

and then a couple lines further : 

`if ($instructavailcheck > 0){ 
        echo json_encode(["message"=>"The instructor is not available at the specified time.", "code"=>401]);
        exit();
 }`

Comment: You have a syntax issue in your query string. Please do that proper string concatenation in the following section '$FromDateTime' between start_date_time and end_date_time . Use PHP string concatenation properly. As you have started the query with a double quote so use string concatenation like '".$FromDateTime."'

Comment: Thank you. I've changed them to `'".$FromDateTime."'` format but the parse error remains the same. I am double checking all the other data to make sure it corresponds..

Comment: The code editor really doesn't seem to like there being " " in the `'".$FromDateTime."'`...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM events_table WHERE
Date_From = 'start_event_date' AND  Date_To = 'end_event_date' AND Time_From = 'start_event_time'  AND  Time_To = 'end_event_time';
```

However, Anirudha's suggestion should be more efficient to manage depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I now have the following : 

`$Instructavailverifysql = "SELECT * FROM ``$instructor_table`` WHERE ('$FromDateTime' between start_date_time and end_date_time) AND ('$ToDateTime' between start_date_time and end_date_time)";
 $instructtavailquery = mysqli_query($db_conx4, $Instructavailverifysql);
 $instructavailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($instructtavailquery);`

I now have two datetime columns as suggested. 

The value of `$instructor_table` is the name of the table I am querying.

Comment: My goal is for the query to return a # of rows should there be an event already created between the two datetime columns in the table.

Comment: I have single ` around the `$instructor_table` - but they wouldn't display correctly above had I only put one.

Comment: I have given you the full solution on my answer. Just create that and test. And if you want to use your table structure let me know I will give solution for that as well.

Comment: No, basically in my solution I have used between clause, so it will check anything between that time range.

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry I'm getting confused between the two answers as these comments are in regards to your (the other) answer

Comment: `$Instructavailverifysql = "SELECT * FROM instructor_table WHERE FromDateTime = '$start_date_time' AND ToDateTime = '$end_date_time'";`